# Which part of the iPhone 8 Plus is this?

Tags: iphone, repair

I decided to repair my phone. I have succesfully disassembled and assembled it. But I got this part left on my table. Any ideas of what it is?

[image: unknown part]

Comment: What interior part did you repair or replace?

Comment: Screen and digitizer. Also home button stopped working but surprisingly touch is OK. Call speaker and light sensor also stopped working for some reason. I'm thinking if this tiny part could be the issue.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But Step No. 33 in ifixit.com's presentation of how to R&R the screen and digitizer notes that overtightening specific screws can render the home button inoperable. See: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+8+Plus+LCD+and+Digitizer+Replacement/111373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the gasket holding the touch chip in place on the original screen assembly, fastened on the metal shield that you transfer from the original assembly to the new one. It is there because the touch chip needs to be in a very specific position to fit down in the phone when closing it. It is however not necessary for operation.

As for the ear speaker and light sensor not working, those are either the result of incorrect placement of the sensor and speaker contact as part of that assembly, when you transfer it from the old to the new screen assembly, or you have damaged the assembly itself, which is very easy to do when you are inexperienced, as it is a delicate part.

The home button part is also delicate and it is somewhat easy to rip its flex cable close to the contact when lifting it off the old screen assembly, which could give the symptoms you describe. Otherwise, try to reseat the contact.